# When to use commas in a sentence that starts with "finally", "additionally", etc.?

Tags: adverbs, commas, sentence-starts, disjuncts

If I have a sentence that starts with *additionally, finally, consequently*, etc. do I always have to put a comma after it? Or is there a different rule?

Answer (score 10):

A sentence adverb (or a *disjunct* or an *introductory adverbial element*) should be followed by a comma in certain circumstances. You can find all the information you could possibly want here:

**[grammartips.homestead.com/adverbs2.html](http://grammartips.homestead.com/adverbs2.html)**

Comment: Excellent link, for which I'll upvote the answer. But ideally you'd have done the spadework to point out that *all* of OP's *introductory adverbial elements* are in fact *conjunctive adverbs*. Which, as your link points out, are optional - with the modern tendency being to omit them. I like the metaphor of optional commas creating superfluous pauses that are **as welcome as speed bumps**!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: They might prevent accidents...

Comment: @Cerberus: Exactly! Reader is accidentally reading too fast, not paying attention, and so misses the significant of crucial clause which should have been preceded by pregnant pause. It's so much easier being a movie director than a writer - you've got total control of the pace.

Comment: Excellent online resource.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it's just a matter of personal preference. Do you want your reader to mentally pause after the first word or not?

Comment: Note the comma after "actually"!

Comment: I did actually think it might lend a touch of 'gravitas' to the answer following, to be preceded by such a portentious pause. Contrasting with the somewhat more informal if not flippant tone of the expansionary second sentence :-)

Comment: I don't understand why it would be a matter of preference. Which sounds right? "Honestly I like the new Microsoft ads." "Actually, they are not gramatical."

Comment: @benc: In certain *specific* contexts, it may well be that the vast majority of writers either would or wouldn't include a comma in some particular sentence. But consider this example from the link in JIP's answer: *Often, the introductory adverb modifies just the verb, as does the word "often"in this sentence.* That first comma can obviously either be present or not - it's a matter of the *effect the writer is aiming for*. Also [,] don't forget that *the modern tendency is to **use less commas***.

Answer (score 8):

If starting a sentence with an introductory word or phrase then, yes, a comma would be required.

> If you need money ask grandma for a loan.
>   Alternatively, rob a bank.

You would not need a comma if the word is used as an adverb in mid-sentence:

> I finally had my refrigerator
>   repaired.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I use it like this: Finally[,] I had my refrigerator repaired.

Comment: Whilst I'm sure most people would put a comma after *Alternatively* there, many people - myself included - might well not bother if you substituted *Or* instead. It's not a matter of absolute rules. Or if there *is* a rule, it's probably *Omit commas wherever this doesn't compromise legibility*.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: A comma would be required in the sentence "Finally, I had my refrigerator repaired". The key is whether the word or phrase is _introductory_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I would say that the formal rule is to always use a comma before an introductory word or phrase. In short, when the sentence doesn't begin with the subject. When writing informally I suppose you could omit the comma to dictate a certain pace to the reader: "Or take the bus".

Comment: @Roflcoptr: In thinking about your example "Finally I had my refrigerator repaired", this may be an example of word inversion rather than use of an introductory word. I suspect that the former wouldn't require a comma, as you are using 'finally' to mean 'at long last' rather than 'lastly'.

Comment: @Snubian: My point is precisely that I don't accept the validity of any *formal rule* in this context, obviously. But let's not get into a pissing contest. If there were to be a formal rule, yours would do well enough.