# Is this a dangling modifier?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Was just reading *The $100 Startup* and came across this sentence:

> Happily, the launch was successful.

Is this a dangling modifier (not sure if that's what it's called)? Or some other error? It seems to me that it's the launch here in the sentence that's going about its business happily, not the author.

Comment: Why do you think it some sort of error?

Comment: "Happily (for me/ for everyone), the launch was successful." -- Ellipsis? :)

Comment: You might look at these questions: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1521 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21532 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/24031

Answer (score 3):

It’s a *disjunct*, also known as a *sentence adverb*, which expresses the attitude of the writer towards the event described. It is not an error.